# making android provide notification for email with specific header

Tags: email, notifications

Currently my gmail in android notify me when there is new mail arrives. I wonder if the notification can limit to the messages with specific words in their title.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In latest version of Gmail you can specify notifications based on labels.

1. Create a filter in Gmail's web interface and assign it to a Label.
2. On your Android device, open the Gmail app, press Menu key and go to `More -> Settings`
3. Tap on your account, scroll down and tap on the "Sync inboxes and labels" option.
4. Tap on the label you created in step 1, and change the preference to "Sync last 4 days" or "Sync all."
5. Go back one step, scroll down and tap on the "Labels to notify" option.
6. Tap on the label name from step 1, and set the notification options to your liking (custom ringtone, vibration, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one trick. Use filters in Gmail to put a label on the message with that particular word. Now in Gmail app go to settings -> Notifications. You'll see option to set notification as per the label.